# Does a method call in in a for loop declaration affect performance?

Tags: java

For example is this

```
for (String s : getStrings()) {
    // do something
}
```

less efficient than this?

```
ArrayList<String> strings = getStrings();
for (String s : strings) {
    // do something
}
```

Would `getStrings()` get called every time, thus affecting performance?

Comment: I think the compiler takes care of that, so both are as efficient.

Comment: It actually makes no difference. The enhanced for loop is compiled into the same code as with using an iterator, so the method will be called only once. See the linked question.

Comment: @Tunaki, thanks for the link